# Kafka Message Broker with AMQP Interface

Tags: apache-kafka, amqp

Is it possible to have Kafka with AMQP support ?

Hi, I am new to Kafka and are in process of analyzing kafka. We like to replace our conventional message broker with Kafka and looking for a few questions.
Our existing broker supports AMQP clients and we would like to use an AMQP connector/interface in Kafka so that our AMQP clients won't feel the infrastructure changes.

Comment: there are things like: https://github.com/strimzi/amqp-kafka-bridge

Answer (score 1):

AMQ clients are not compatible with the Kafka protocol, and out of the box, Apache Kafka has no such support.

In the latest release, Confluent provides an [AMQ source connector](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) which means that you need to run Kafka Connect processes alongside your Kafka brokers to ease transition.

There are other, similar services you can find elsewhere, as mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

look at

https://github.com/yumok/amqp-kafka-bridge

> AMQP - Apache Kafka bridge This project provides a software component
> which acts as a bridge between AMQP (Advanced Message Queuing
> Protocol) based clients and Apache Kafka cluster.
>
> It provides a different way to interact with Apache Kafka because the
> latter supports natively only custom (proprietary) protocol. Thanks to
> the bridge, all clients which can speak AMQP (which is a standard
> OASIS and ISO-IEC) protocol can connect to Apache Kafka cluser in
> order to send and receive messages to/from topics.